# Reading incoming SMS from a computer through an API over WiFi or internet

Tags: sms

I want to read incoming SMS'es from my computer, through an API, preferably in Python but I can write the Python code myself if the API is plain HTTP or JSON.

The phone uses the same WiFi as the computer, but the phone is not rooted and is not cable-connected to the computer. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues, so we can't really help with APIs and code-related issues since they are out of scope.

Comment: You need a couple of things for this. First, in recent Android versions only the default messaging app can read and send SMS. So you need an app that can be set to be default as SMS app, and that also allows at least a CLI functionality to allow accessing SMS. Second, you need a trigger for incoming SMS. Your SMS app or an automation app should provide a way to inform us about an incoming SMS. Third, you need a server (that would provide API) to act on that trigger and start accessing relevant SMS. NodeJS in Termux can be the server that would provide API. It can listen for events.

Comment: use old phone with old apps, no need to set as default then. I used to chat in realtime via sms on windows PC few years ago with MyPhoneExplorer (works even on wifi via adb tcpip)